# is rpi suitable for hard real time ECG signal processing?

Tags: real-time, freertos

I am working on moniroting system for medicacl care and I can't deside what to use , having that the processing includes denoising , segmentation feature extraction and machine learning 
another functionality of the system is to generate notification through phone calls ,
through my research online I came across one video where they say that rpi does not include timer which make it unsuitable for RT processing unless you perform some modification I didn't come to know what it is that I have to add 
further more there is the posiibility to use an RTOS , how is that supposed to add to my system and is RTAI https://www.rtai.org/ a good choice in this case , finally can I still classify this project as embedded system event though I'll be working on an os ?

Comment: The Pi is not a microcontroller.  This question appears too broad and opinion based for this site.

Comment: Welcome -- please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are mentioning phone calls, you may want to design a real-time capable gadget that communicates with a smartphone through bluetooth or wifi, and do the phone and user interface stuff through an app on the phone.

It's feasible and cheap to make such a gadget with the Raspberry Pi Zero W, but you need to design a custom HAT for the interfacing and maybe realtime processing features. The latter depends on your exact real time requirements.

In general, everything in the ms range does not need a special OS or controller, but can be reached by a normal Linux process. Kernel drivers can offer real time in the 100µs range. For anything "harder", you need an RTOS or an µC on the HAT.